# initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue in ctor

Tags: c++, casting, initialization

I'm writing a program with a component virtual class that details the behavior of a component that needs to access registers on a device via a bus. The various operations on the registers are described in a virtual class, which is independent of the type of bus used. The derived RegisterI2C class implements register access functions for an I2C bus. The ComponentI2C class corresponds to the use of a component using the I2C bus. In this class, I try to define the component_reg function, which calls the constructor of the RegisterI2C class, but at compile time I get the following error:

> initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue C/C++(461).

I've tried different types of casting but haven't found the solution. So I'd appreciate it if anyone had an idea :)

```
class Component;
class Register {  // defines access method to registers
 public:
  Register(Component *parent, int reg) : parent_(parent), register_(reg) {}
  virtual int read() = 0;  // read the register
  Component *const parent_; // parent component
  int register_; // the register to operate on
};
class Component {  // defines what a component do.Uses Register functions
  virtual Register &component_reg(int reg) = 0; // return a Register we use for op on comp
};
class I2C {};  // provides I2C busfunctions
class ComponentI2C;
class RegisterI2C : public Register {  // implement Register func for I2C bus
 public:
  RegisterI2C(Component *parent, int reg) : Register(parent, reg) {}
/* use I2C class methods through downcasting Component to ComponentI2C */
  int read() override { return 0; }
};
class ComponentI2C : public Component, public I2C {
 public:
  RegisterI2C &component_reg(int reg) override { return {this, reg}; }; // **PROBLEM HERE**
};
```

Note: returning component_reg as a pointer is not an option :(

Comment: You're returning a reference to a local / temporary object.

Comment: Also, your [mre] might have cut out too much, since you are trying to `return {this,reg};`, but that will attempt to make a `Register` object, which has a pure-virtual function; thus, compiling your above snippet actually gives a different error.

Comment: There just isn't anything of type `Register` or derived from `Register`  anywhere you can return a reference to (or a pointer to, for that matter). `{this, reg}` isn't such a thing. So I'm afraid you need to come up with Plan B.

Comment: I just edited the code class ComponentI2C the return type for component_reg should be RegisterI2C (cant return virtual function)

Comment: You got rid of one error, namely `Register` being an abstract class. But you still have the other fundamental error, and it *will* stay. There is simply no object that you can reference. You cannot return a reference to a local variable (doesn't live long enough) or to a temporary (won't bind *and* doesn't live long enough). You could in principle return a reference to a member of `Component`, but you need to make sure different registers correspond to different members, so you need an array of registers in each component. Or you could return something by value (needs redesign),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComponentI2C::component_reg()` is returning a reference to a *temporary* `RegisterI2C` object. Don't do that. Declare a data member of type `RegisterI2C` inside of `ComponentI2`, and then return a reference to that member.

```
class Component;

class Register {
 public:
  Register(Component *parent, int reg) : parent_(parent), register_(reg) {}
  virtual ~Register() = default;
  virtual int read() = 0;
  Component *const parent_;
  int register_;
};

class Component {
  virtual Register& component_reg(int reg) = 0;
};

class I2C {};

class ComponentI2C;

class RegisterI2C : public Register {
 public:
  RegisterI2C(Component *parent, int reg) : Register(parent, reg) {}
  int read() override { return 0; }
};

class ComponentI2C : public Component, public I2C {
  RegisterI2C regI2C_;
 public:
  ComponentI2C() : regI2C_(this, 0) {}
  Register& component_reg(int reg) override { regI2C_.register_ = reg; return regI2C_; };
};
```

Comment: Excellent solution this is exactly what I was looking for.
I have successfully tested a solution like this
`std::unique_ptr<Register> component_reg(int reg) {
    std::unique_ptr<Register> r(new RegisterI2C{this, reg, channel, 0});
    return r;
  }`
but your solution is much better

Comment: added in my final program and works like a charm. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

The solution I found is:

```
 public:
  RegisterI2C &component_reg(int reg) override { return *new RegisterI2C(this, reg); };
```

Note you should take care of deleting the poinnter after usage

Comment: _Note you should take care of deleting the pointer after usage_ Why aren't you using smart pointers?

Comment: That's a terrible solution :/

Comment: This solution leaks memory, unless the caller calls `delete` on the returned reference: `Register &reg = comp.component_reg(...); ... delete &reg;` This is not a good solution, just don't do it!